# Is there a word or phrase for "person of the same ethnicity"?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for something that is the equivalent of "fellow countryman", but for ethnicity. Using [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/304567/is-there-a-word-for-a-person-from-another-race) as a starting point, I've been thinking it might be along the lines of "congeneous", though really "homogenous" seems to be more fitting, but too general. Any ideas?

Comment: This is quite difficult. The problem is that *ethnic* (and *ethnicity*) has really only been used in its modern sense since about 1900. Its ancient meaning was similar to *pagan*, meaning -"neither Christian nor Jewish".  I don't think you will do any better than - *of common ethnicity*, or *common acculturation*.

Comment: "fellow X" for example "fellow Arab"

Comment: I'm staking a claim for "ethnicompatriot" :)

Answer (score 1):

I think an appropriate word could be co-ethnics.

Comment: To be a good answer, you should include a supporting reference/link for your chosen word.

Comment: You could show a Google 1-gram; there is evidence that the term was introduced in the 1940s, and that it is being used more and more. Almost certainly 'in the lexis' now.